# Error: column "data_type" of relation does not exist

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to user a trigger to return the 'data_type' of a column from my table. [SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a384f8/1) has the whole trigger...but the ket bits are:

```
 FOR each_column IN
        SELECT
            attname as column_name,
            format_type(atttypid, atttypmod) AS data_type
        FROM
            pg_attribute
        WHERE
            attrelid =
            (
                SELECT
                    oid
                FROM
                    pg_class
                WHERE
                    relname = tg_relname
           LIMIT 1 )
        AND attnum > 0
    LOOP
```

The error I am getting (at the end of this query is):

```
ERROR: column "data_type" of relation does not exist Where: PL/pgSQL function log.insert_history() line 94 at SQL statement
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing...does anyone see it?

Comment: Show us  the complete code

Comment: There is no `data_type` column in the `create table log.history ...` statement. Later you are trying to insert data into it: `INSERT INTO log.history(..., column_name, data_type, new_val, ...)`

Comment: @Abelisto - correct. I see it. I updated with my answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL below to get all columns from table YOUR_SCHEMA.YOUR_TABLE_NAME:

```
SELECT
    a.attname, LOWER(format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod)) AS type, d.adsrc, 
    a.attnotnull, a.atthasdef
FROM
    pg_attribute a 
        LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON (a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum)
WHERE 
    a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
    AND a.attrelid = (SELECT oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_class WHERE relname = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
        AND relnamespace = (SELECT oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace WHERE nspname = 'YOUR_SCHEMA'))
ORDER BY 
    a.attnum;
```

Comment: BTW there is the trick that allows to simplify such queries, for example: `select * from pg_attribute where attrelid = 'information_schema.columns'::regclass;`

Answer (score 0):

@Abelisto was correct - I forgot to add the statement in 'create table'. Oops!

Working solution in [SQL FIDDLE is HERE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c4dc8/1).